# Sound not working on my PC running Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound, alsa, hdmi

I was using the previous version of UBUNTU 18.04 and everything was working great, one day it asked me to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 and had a to start from zero for the installation of the OS.

When the Os was installed the SOUND only cam out thru the HDMI port and to the monitor speakers.

The sound care is recognized on the terminal window, If I fo to settings and then to AUDIO i cant see the Sound card there.

I tried another version od UBUNTU to see if the problem persisted, the version I used was UBUNTU STUDIO 18.10.

Sound came out thru the sound card wit no problems.

What can I do in order to have UBUNTU 18.10 installed and the soundcard working ?